# batch files combining into each other

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 batch files "1 menu and 1 for holding some clock jobs"

and i want to combine em

so i added menus codes to clocks one and i can use call

.. which intercepts the clock

is there a way to make that instead of call i can use it like start "so another cmd window pop up" and i wont be intercepting the clock

or do i need to use external vbasic code...

the real thing is i dont want to `use another external batch` and/or `echo stuff >>2nd.bat`

Comment: How much code would be in the second batch file? If it is a single command you can just run `start command`.

Comment: no it is a full batch file "at least 22 lines of code" D:

Comment: Your best off keeping them in separate .bat files, if you need it to open in a new window.

Comment: well that was my 1st solution but i will use bat to exe converters out there and i cant use 2 exes in bat i guess D:

Comment: You should be able to convert multiple batch files to a single executable. [This converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bat2exe/) claims to be able to convert a folder to an executable.

Comment: If you post the code then you'll probably get a solution.  There's not enough info to know where you are having issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I'm reading your question... if you want both of them to open as ONE batch file and run at the same time... or open both I'll do both...

1. Running same time in same Command-Line

I believe at the same time you want to use something called "multithreading" which uses 0 external code... So pretty much what it is is run two "threads" or two instances at once... In order to do this use your code as this:

```
::Useless
IF NOT "%1" == "" goto :%1
start /b %~nx0 [thread]
:1
::Code
:thread
::Code
```

What ends up happening is there running at the same time... so you can do this...

IF NOT "%1" == "" goto :%1
   start /b %~nx0 clock
   :1
   ::Code
   :clock
   call clock
   ::Other code

Doing this means 1 and clock will run at the same time...

And for the second one...
Simply use start
3 files.

```
start.bat
1.bat
clock.bat
```

start equals
    start [dir]1.bat
    start [dir]clock.bat
and so on...
I hope this helped you.

Comment: Well i didnt quite get what you meant by 1st method but i liked it . it seems like i can use it with my application.